# How to represent the points of intersecting lines in set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question is as follows: Let $L _1,L_2,\dots,L_n$ be distinct lines in the Euclidean plane, and let $A$ be the set of points formed by intersections of these lines. Characterize $A$ using set notation and quantifiers.

The reason I'm asking this is because my professor has not really explained set notation very well yet and I just don't have any idea where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to clarify what you mean by set notation.

However, might you be looking for something like:

$ A = \{ x : x \in L_i \cap L_j,  ( i,j) : 1 \le i <j \le n\}$

Basically, the notation above just lists out whatever you're saying in English:

The set $A$ is the set of all $x$ that lie on the intersection of $L_i$ and $L_j$ for $i,j$ within the index set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. The inequalities are just to avoid repetition, and you can do without them.

Comment: Then you might as well write $$\bigcup_{1\le i<j\le n} L_i\cap L_j$$ (And you do need at least a condition guaranteeing that $i\ne j$).

Comment: Assuming the lad is just being introduced to this stuff, he's probably been taught of sets in the $\{ x : \dots \}$ form. No need to introduce notation he's never seen.

Comment: And the $\forall$ in your suggestion is directly wrong. Presently you're saying that a point is in $A$ if and only if _every_ pair of lines intersect at that point.

Comment: Ach, yes. Shall fix.

Comment: Additionally, it is wrong notation to put the quantifiers _after_ the formula they range over. The proper syntax is $(\forall x)\phi$ and $(\exists x)\phi$ (with some freedom regarding where and whether to put parentheses), never $\phi(\forall x)$ or $\phi(\exists x)$.

Comment: Awesome guys.  Thanks for both of your help.  I understand this a little bit better now

Answer (score 0):

Let $L_i$ denote the set of points on the line `` $l_i$''.

Then Intersections $= L_1 \cap ... \cap L_n $.

Cuz the intersection of two sets, $A,B$ is $A \cap B$. This is similar to the interection of two lines, the roots of $ax + by = c$ and $a'x + b'y = c'$, We get a set of one root in this intersection.

Comment: That's the intersection of all lines in the sequence; which is at most one point.  We want the union of intersections of two distinct lines in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Lines are sets of points, and you want the union of the set of intersections of two *distinct* members of a set of lines.

$$A = \mathop{\bigcup_{k=1}^n\bigcup_{j=1}^n}_{j\neq k} (l_j\cap l_k) $$

Or did you want set-constructor notation?

$$A = \{p\mid \exists l_a{\in}\{l_1...l_n\}\; \exists l_b{\in}\{l_1...l_n\}:(l_a\neq l_b\wedge p\in l_a\cap l_b)\} $$